# rospack find foobar

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to do the tutorial :
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Package%20by%20Hand

I did already:

```
 source /home/fschiano/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

And I am in the `catkin_ws` folder.

But when I give the command

```
rospack find foobar
```

I get the error:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'foobar' not found
```

How can I solve this?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194674/rospack-find-foobar/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try a `rospack profile` (after you've sourced `setup.bash`).

If that doesn't work, make sure `foobar` actually is a ROS package (has a manifest: `package.xml`).

Also make sure there is no `CATKIN_IGNORE` file in the package directory.

---

Edit: your last comment does not correspond to what you wrote in your OP. Anyway, these steps should work (in a fresh terminal):

```
cd /home/fschiano/catkin_ws
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
# (this step is optional, only if the next step doesn't immediately work)
rospack profile
rospack find foobar
```

If `rospack` cannot find `foobar` then, something is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2014-10-10**:
When I type `rospack profile` I get :

```
Full tree crawl took 0.014759 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
----------
```

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2014-10-10**:
0.014213   /opt/ros/indigo/share
0.000038 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc
0.000005 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc/liborocos-kdl

I am in the `~/catkin_ws`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-10**:
great. Now again try `rospack find foobar` (in the same terminal).

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2014-10-10**:
I always get : `[rospack] Error: package 'foobar' not found`

I am in this folder

```
/home/fschiano/catkin_ws
```

and I do first :

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

then

```
rospack profile
```

and then

```
rospack find foobar
```

`catkin_ws` folder has to stay in the ros folder?